What is the longest possible (current material science) for a human weight-bearing 3” thick, 5’ wide slab attached to a wall on one end?
For my story, I need a cliff face with a slab sticking out of the middle of it, like an inflexible diving board. I need it to be 5 feet wide (exact) and 3-to-6 inches thick (thinner is better). I need it to stick straight out from the middle of the cliff face and for most humans to be able to stand on it without it noticeably flexing (meaning the person on it feels like they’re standing on a rigid plane when they step onto the unsupported end of it).
At 3” thick, what is the longest such slab I can plausibly have with current material science? What material is the slab made of? How much longer do I get if I allow more thickness? I’m hoping for something measured in meters.

You might get better answers to this on Engineering SE. I presume you don't mind if your platform is not a homogenous solid? It's much easier to support 100kg/m of steel lattice and a 70kg person than 1000kg/m of solid steel and a 70kg person.

It would also help if you numerically define "noticeable flex" and specify whether the cliff-board intersection is fixed and indestructible, or if not, what it's made of.

A simple strut would bend. You could make a strut that does not deflect at all if it has a cable below the upper surface which is actively tensioned to compensate for the weight upon it.

Does it need to be flat? I'm thinking of a structure like a metal tape-measure shape, with a material stressed like that too - would that fit in with your requirements?

I agree with @gs. It will take specialized knowledge to answer this because we humans don't have a reason to build such an extension. We do build bridges, and while I can't find the longest unsupported span, I've personally seen spans of hundreds of feet. Keep in mind that you need to stick into the cliff +/- one third of the external extension depending on the weight and stability of the mass above your extension. And frankly, you could likely make quite a long length out of carbon nanotubes with internal I-beam reinforcement.  However... (*Continued*)

... do you have a goal? Asking how long, how large, what's the "biggest" or any other open-ended length is often not practical. What happens if it's not a length that works for you? Do you expect to be judged by the length you choose?

How far back into the cliff can it go? Material strength/stiffness isn't necessarily the limiting factor so much as anchorage and cantilever forces.

How do you notice that the flexing? I would imagine you might not notice a constant deflection of a few millimetres, but you would notice the bounce as you walked.

@Escapeddentalpatient. Yes it needs to be flat. A rectangular slab of some construction.

@JBH The goal is a particular visual effect for architecture, a series of these walkable slabs arranged in patterns creating an image when viewed at a particular angle. As I said, I'm looking for something in meters... if you want harder numbers, let's say 20 meters or, as a fall back, 10 meters.

@RichardKirk I thought my original statement was clear, so I'm not sure how to clarify further. If I step on a diving board, I notice it flex when I walk on it. It's bouncy. If I step on a 20x5x5 cm bar of steel locked on one end in an industrial vice on a table, its completely immovable to all my senses. It feels as solid as the ground or a typical staircase or ladder step. I want to extend that out. A lot (see previous clarification to JBH).

@SRM If the board has a vibration frequency and you jump or walk at that frequency then it will resonate. This is what happened with the Millennium footbridge in London. You would need damping.

Cheers. Please [edit] your post with the goals. Never assume people will read comments. Also, to set expectations, the [tag:hard-science] tag is ruthless. Answers that don't embrace its requirements are threatened with deletion. You may not get any answers simply because there may not be any civil/structural/material engineers that haunt our stack. If, after a day or two, you don't get answers... consider re-asking the question on [engineering.se]. Frankly, it's usually best to ask science-only questions on the appropriate stacks. Nothing about your question actually involves worldbuilding.

Do you mean a slab we CAN create, or a slab that is theoretically possible with known science? The latter is answerable, sort of. A slab of artificial diamond with no major flaws, that is about 5 feet wide and 3 inch thick, could be made about 4.2 miles long before it snapped. Before snapping, it would actually bend due to elastic strain, by about 9%. Its hard to determine at what length it would not bend at all  (if imperceptibly), I would ballpark 1% bend at about a half of a mile. Human weight is irrelevant here in comparison, so it would not bend under a person anyway.

the theoretical best glass slab possible that would not snap or perceptibly bend at this thickness and width would be about 200 feet long, but it is absolutely impossible to make one without catastrophic flaws.

"Without it noticeably flexing" needs a numerical specification. Is a one millimeter flex noticeable? Once centimeter? One percent of the length of the plank? It is very hard to compute anything without data.

@AlexP can you notice a 1mm flex on a stair? Come on. I asked a reasonable question and got a lot of excessive pedantic responses. Distinctly unhelpful. My observation: there is increasing unwillingness of Worldbuilding to answer the question asked. This is frustrating to me.

I do not think that material is the restrictive factor here. Gravity is.
Depending on the gravitational situation on your fictional planet there will be a force applied to the "end" of the board, making it bend downwards.
This force can easily be computed by
  F = m * g      Force (gravitational) = mass * gravity constant

  F measured in Newtons (N), 
  m in Kilograms (kg), 
  g is an acceleration, measured in metres per seconds² (m/s²)

The gravitational force the board has to withstand is the mass of the board (plus anyone standing on it or exerting force on it, like wind for example) times the gravitational constant of the planet.
For reference, you can assume earth's gravitational constant being roughly 10m/s² (really something about 9,81 and depending on where on the planet you are at, but those deviations by position are negligible here).
As you can see, if you make your board thicker or longer (or wider), it gets heavier, therefore the force which bends it also increases - tenfold! You cannot get more stability by making the board thicker and longer.

Edit: I provide you with some more maths on the topic to understand how the factors you mentioned influence each other.
To obtain the mass of the slab, you can compute this by using the volume of the slab and the density factor of the material it's made of. Like this:
V = w * b * l   Volume = Width * Beam (Thickness) * Length

V is measured in cubic metres (m³),
w,b,l in metres (m).

Then you can insert this into the formula:
m = V * R       Mass = Volume * Density factor (greek "Rho")

m measured in kilograms (kg),
V in cubic metres (m³),
R in kilograms per cubic metre (kg/m³).

For reference: Water in liquid form has the density factor of R=1, wood is about 200-1200kg/m³, iron (say "steel") about 7800kg/m³ and concrete (say "stone") something about 800-5000kg/m³.
You need to know that a cubic metre of water weighs the same as one metric ton (=1000kg). If you divide your volume by 1000 (10 in each dimension) you have deci-metres (=10cm) cubed. A cube of 10cm length in each dimension filled with water is equivalent to a weight of 1 kilogram.
Next, you need to add in a factor accounting for the elasticity (in your case the "rigidness" of the material), let's name that x (Disclaimer: I do not know if there is a material property that can be measured like this, so the following is for demonstrational purposes only). Think about the scale of x being between 0 = totally wobbly like a rubberband, and infinite = totally rigid, no wobbling possible - which is a fictional material not existing on earth. If you want to have something realistic in between, like steel, insert a very high number, like one million for example.
Also note, if a material has no possibility of bending, this makes it totally prone to breaking apart. The material is very "brittle" because of the rigidness. The more rigid a material is, the less force it can sustain. Think of chalk for example.
This means: If you do not want the slab to bend at all, this would result in an infinite strong force pulling on the end of the slab. Which means it breaks. If it is allowed to bend "a little" the force would still be million-fold or more (think: "extremely high" like in "unsustainably high").
There is another take, being that the slab is a kind of lever. This means (without looking those laws of physics up now), the force downward increases "rapidly" with the length of the lever (the board). "Rapidly" meaning something like in "squared". And if there is no counter force on the other side of the board (which needs to be at least the same length away from the center as the slab being outside the cliff, the imbalance makes the board break immediately.
Let's put all the formulas together and you get:
F = m * g (the starting point)
F = V * R * g   (inserting m=V*R)
F = w * b * l * R * g  (inserting V=w*b*l)
F = w * b * l * R * g * x * l² (appending x and l²)

Given your dimensions it converts to roughly b=3"=8cm=0,08m and w=5'=150cm=1,5m.
Now you can insert all the values, except for the length (simplifying with R=8000 instead of 7800 for something like "steel"):
F = 1,5 * 0,08 * l * 8,000 * 10 * 1,000,000 * l²

Let's simplify it a bit. w and b do not seem to be that much of a changer, so I leave them out and multiply the factors to yield:
F = l³ * 80,000,000,000
I would like you to note that this value is "very high" :D In words and assuming the length l to be 1m, the force is about 80 billion Newtons. Divided by 10 (gravitational constant g to be exact, and another 1000 to get to metric tons) and yield an equivalent mass of 8 million tons - that is about the estimated mass of the great pyramid of gizah). And the one variable left, the length, has an influence on the force of "cubed" (l² * l). If you let l be one metre, l³ is still 1. But take l=10m and you have another factor of 1000 in the end result.
You can say the factor x makes the end result look bad. But even if you let x out of the formula, you would have 80,000 Newtons * l³. For reference: A force of 80,000 Newtons (divide it by 10 or exactly g, the gravitational constant of the planet) is equivalent to a weight of 8000kg or 8 metric tons hanging on the edge of the slab.
Oh, and I forgot, taking the persons into account. The extra force of persons can be obtained as in the beginning by F_persons = m * g = (sum of all weights of all persons) * gravitational constant. This would need to be added to the force already computed so far. It seems to be negligible, if there is not a large number of people supposed to be on the slab (give or take 700 Newtons for a 70kg person does not change anything).
Please keep in mind that the computations above are not a complete model of the stability of materials hanging on a wall. It is a simplification still. But one that can give you an impression on what to expect. (In my computations you could for example make the thickness of the slab close to zero and therefore the force also would be very very small - but of course something thinner also means something less stable and so on).

You cannot ask what is the possible length of the slab and also asking what material this one is made of. Because the answer would be a table needing to list all possible materials and the resulting lengths before the slab is bent downwards "too much", which you also did not specify, but could be assumed to be something between a millimetre and a centimetre maybe.
A little material science comes into play, because you would need a value in Newtons for each material describing at what limit it would break.
So, the best I can do is giving you a rough understanding. The maximum length of such a slab, pertruding perpendicular out of the cliff and not having any kind of suspension or other support beams, is in the range of one or two metres (on earth). No matter what material you use. Even the strongest material alone will not be able to withstand the forces it exerts on itself when made longer and longer.
This is the reason why bridges always have some kind of support. This is also the reason why power cables hang down in a curve between power poles. If you wanted them to hang straight, the poles would need to withstand forces (and therefore would need energy) getting close to "infinite". So it is not feasible.

Yes, everything bends under load. Bridges bend under load. Without knowing what is the allowed amount of bending nothing can be calculated.
